# Node.js routes with parameters

Tags: node.js, express

My first time using Node.js/express routes, I cannot match when I use parameters

```
<a href="/produtos/1/produto-test">

 app.use('/produtos', produtosRouter);

//below the produtosRouter, function
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('produtos/:id/:slug', { title: 'test test.' });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
router.get('/:id/:slug', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('<name_of_the_template>', { title: 'test test.'});
});
```